# Symfony2 uses wrong "x-forwarded-for" on AWS Load Balancer / 2 Ip addresses

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, x-forwarded-for

simple / small question.

My Amazon AWS ELB sends me the following headers.

```
x-forwarded-for     84.134.167.231, 172.31.17.157
x-forwarded-host    app.example.org
x-forwarded-port    443
x-forwarded-proto   https
x-forwarded-server  ip-172-31-11-2.eu-central-1.compute.internal
```

But the request uses the second one, the local machine ip address. - 172.31.17.157

Do anyone know how to fix this problem?
Is it possible to overwrite the Get IP functions of Symfony?

Thanks in Advance!

//edit 1 - HTTPs Configuration

```
    files:
      /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
          LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
          Listen 443
          <VirtualHost *:443>
            <Proxy *>
              Order deny,allow
              Allow from all
            </Proxy>

            SSLEngine             on
            SSLCertificateFile    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
            SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"
            SSLCipherSuite        EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
            SSLProtocol           All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
            SSLHonorCipherOrder   On
            SSLSessionTickets     Off

            Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
            Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
            Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

            ProxyPass / http://localhost:80/ retry=0
            ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:80/
            ProxyPreserveHost on
            RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https" early

          </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I think you'll find the ELB does *not* "send" you this, but rather your web server is *adding* 172.31.17.157, which is the ELB node's IP,  to `X-Forwarded-For`, to what the ELB sends to you (84.134.167.231).  This will be an issue with your web server configuration.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I added you the Configuration of my web server for https part. There is a proxy for HTTP. Maybe this proxy adds this header? How to fix the problem then? Thanks ;-)

Comment: It wouldn't be in this section of the config, which is related to SSL.  I am unfamiliar with Symphony, but it looks like [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/request/load_balancer_reverse_proxy.html) is telling you that if you configure something like `trusted_proxies: [172.31.0.0/16]` then the extra addresses at the end of `X-Forwarded-For` will be disregarded.  `172.31.0.0/16` is what I assume to be the CIDR supernet of your VPC, based on what you've shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to overwrite getIP function (or anything equivalent) to get it work for ELB. Note, only for ELB.

The underlying issue is that there is no universal agreed on standard for `X-Forwarded-For`.

Most proxy tools, such as Nginx, will set `X-Forwarded-For: client, proxy1, proxy2`. 
However, ELB will set `X-Forwarded-For: proxy1, proxy2, client`.

Therefore, most web frameworks will have IP spoofing issue while using ELB.

The fix is simple, just need to pick the last part of `X-Forwarded-For`. But as you can imagine, if a request is routed through multiple proxies that uses different standards, then there is no easy way to find the real IP address in the end.